# Receiving "SLF4J" logging messages by using apache httpclient

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, httpclient

I need to use the apache httpclient library for a project. I downloaded the zip file "httpcomponents-client-5.0.3-bin" from http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi and created a userLibrary in eclipse with the external jar files which are in the lib folder. I added the userLibrary to the classpath.

By running the code:

```
public abstract class JsonParser {
    
    static JsonObject jObj = null;
    
    public static JsonObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {
        try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault()) {
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            String jSon = JsonParser.readJsonString(httpResponse);
            jObj = (JsonObject) com.google.gson.JsonParser.parseString(jSon);           
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Logging will be implemented later with other resources
        }       
        return jObj;
    }
    
    private static String readJsonString(HttpResponse httpResponse) {
        String result = null;
        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(((BasicClassicHttpRequest) httpResponse).getEntity().getContent());
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();           
            while (scanner.hasNext())
                sb.append(scanner.next());          
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
        return result;
    }

}
```

I receive the following logging messages in the eclipse console:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

They are caused by this line of code in the try catch statement in the method getJSONFromUrl:

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
```

I have no experience with apache maven so far. Do I have to install apache maven to solve this problem or could it be something else?

Comment: You should use maven, because in the medium term it will make your life much better, but this problem can be fixed by adding slf4j-simple.jar to your class path. Did you read http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder as the error message suggested?

Comment: Thank you so much. It works now (I downloaded the jar file from the following link: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-simple/1.7.30/slf4j-simple-1.7.30.jar). I visited http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder before. But I was not sure what I had to do (I was unfortunately uncertain because of apache maven. Many thanks for your advice with maven. I will try to become familiar with it.

Comment: Technically you had to do nothing. Something you were calling makes use of SLF4J, a logging API, which tries to find one of several implementation backends on the classpath. Without it, there just won't be any logs from using that library. It only matters if you're also going to use SLF4J for logging, in which case your logging would be aggregated with anything the HttpClient logs since you get one implementation across your application.